# Proof of inequality in $\mathbb{R^+}$

Tags: inequality

I have this statement:

> You have this fraction: $\frac{p}{q}$, where:
>
> $q > p$ and $q,p \in \mathbb{R^+}$
>
> Proof if $\frac{p}{q} < \frac{p+1}{q+2}$

Basically my development was:

$i)$ $\frac{p}{q}$ has an interval of $(0, 1)$

$i.a) \frac{p+1}{q+2} = \frac{p}{q+2} + \frac{1}{q+2}$

$ii)$ We can notice that $\frac{p}{q} > \frac{p}{q+2}$

$iii)$ According with the last. Let's suppose that $\frac{p}{q} < \frac{p+1}{q+2}$ is true. That is true, if and only if, $\frac{1}{q+2} < \frac{p}{q} - \frac{p}{q+2}$.

I think the step $ iii) $ of this way:

Let $k = \frac{p}{q} - \frac{p}{q+2}$, therefore $\frac{p}{q}$  is $k$ units bigger than $\frac{p}{q+2}$, to "counteract" this, i need that $\frac{1}{q+2}$ be greater than the difference $ k $(from step $i.a)$, and therefore be bigger than $\frac {p} {q}$

$iv)$ Assuming that $\frac{1}{q+2} < \frac{p}{q} - \frac{p}{q+2}$, i will multiply it by $(q+2)$, now i have:

$1 + p< \frac{p(q+2)}{q}$, that is:

$1 + p< \frac{p}{q} *^(q+2)$

I'll write the interval of the left and right side of this inequality.

$[1, \infty^+) < (0, 1) * [2, \infty^+)$ ( assuming that $p,q$ they are infinitely small positives)

Until here I have arrived. In fact, I do not know if it is correct (if it is NOT, I would like to know why), otherwise I would like to know how to continue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this statement is not true, take p=1 q=2

Comment: what do you want to prove????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{p}{q} < \frac{p+1}{q+2}\iff p(q+2)<q(p+1) \iff pq+2p<pq+q \iff 2p<q$$

Comment: I also got that inequality, but i need to prove if $2p < q$?

Comment: Since every step is $\iff$ the condition 2p<q is equivalent to the given inequality therefore the given inequality is true $\iff 2p<q$.

Comment: So with $2p < q$ i can say that is false because the original statement says that $ p < q$ and it is equivalent to $2p < 2q$, but isn't equivalent to $2p < q$, therefore is a contradiction?

Comment: Yes of course, as shown we have that the given inequality is true if and only if 2p<q therefore it is false (in general) assuming p<q. For example for p=1 and q=3 it is true but for p=1 and q=2 it is false.

Comment: In other words p<q is not sufficient to guarantee that the inequality is always true since we need 2p<q.

Comment: Many thanks :).

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\frac{p}{q} < \frac{p+1}{q+2}\quad\iff\quad p(q+2) = pq + 2p< q(p+1) = pq + q\quad\iff\quad 2p < q\ ,$$
where we used the fact that $q>0$.

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are real so ???

Comment: @greedoid So what?

Comment: You tell me.......

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud We have typed almost the same answer!

Comment: Can you explain me how you arrive the right side of the "if and only if"?

Comment: @Mattiu I took away the term $pq$ on both sides of the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove it, since it is false. Take $p=2$ and $q=3$. It is true that $p<q$, but it is false that $\frac pq<\frac{p+1}{q+2}$.

Comment: Can you proof it, please?

Comment: @Mattiu Do you want me to prove that it is false that $\frac23<\frac35$? Is that it?

Comment: I mean a proof in algebraic way, instead of special numeric cases

Comment: @Mattiu I cannot prove a false statement. And neither can you.

Comment: You proved it was false with a special numerical case. I need to prove that it is false, algebraically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mattiu In order to prove that it is false, a single example is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Let $2p\ge q$.  For instance,  $p=2, q=3$.  Then $\frac{p+1}{q+2}=\frac35\lt\frac23$.